# Check all unchecked chekboxes created by bootstrap multiselect

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I need to find a way to check all checkboxes on a web form, created by bootstrap-multiselect.

I tried with code like below, but no luck, none of current checkboxes are checked:

```
function checkUnchecked() {

    var all = $(this);
    $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
       $(this).prop("checked", all.prop("checked"));
    });
    $('#resortId').multiselect('rebuild');
}
```

All multiselect fields on a form are dynamically created, so there is no way I can select them using calls like:

```
$('#resortId').multiselect('select', ['1', '2', '4']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this java script,

```
function cat(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('cat[]');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

your html file should be like this

```
 <label>
            <input type="checkbox" onClick="cat(this)">
            Select All </label>
```

this is to select all,and your remaining chekbox should be like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cat[]"  value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I  think the problem is that you are declaring "all" outside the loop. Anyway, you don't need to use the multiselect, do you? I don't get the point of your "all" statement.

```
function checkUnchecked() {

    $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
       $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
    $('#resortId').multiselect('rebuild');
}
```